# Excel VBA Application.StatusBar in Worksheet_Deactivate fails with 50290

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Worksheet, which updates the StatusBar based on which cell is selected (this works fine). My problem is, with the code that sets the StatusBar back to empty when the user goes to another Worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Application.StatusBar = vbNullString ' Run time error here
End Sub
```

Err.Description is: "Method 'StatusBar' of object '_Application' failed", Err.Number is: 50290.

This error occurs only if the user changes from Worksheet to Worksheet rapidly (by pressing Ctrl+PgUp or Ctrl+PgDown) and does not happen in case of switching to another Sheet slowly.

Why do I have this error?

Answer (score 1):

Just set it to False

```
Application.StatusBar = False
```

from Microsoft:

> This property returns False if Microsoft Excel has control of the status bar. To restore the default status bar text, set the property to False; this works even if the status bar is hidden.

Comment: oh, If that doesn't help there might be an Issue with the references, I found somewhere else:
https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/application-screenupdating.3585123/

Check From the editor Tools -> References  and what you have ticked there
It's about ScreenUpdating but the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. When an event handler starts execution, the Excel Application may not be ready, so this has to be checked if the code refers to objects related to the Application:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If Application.Ready = False Then Exit Sub
    ' Rest of the code referring to Application.x or Me.y or ActiveSheet.z, etc.
End Sub
```